How do I freeze (apply) an animation?
I am creating a model for 3d printing, and what I want is the result of an animation sequence.
I have done this previously with the cloth modifier. in that case you can just apply the modify, and it freezes the model in whatever frame it was at at that moment.
What I am doing now is a rigid body animation - a bunch of things falling I a pile basically. There does not seem to be an apply button here. I can see an "Animated Transforms to delta" option in Object - Apply, but that just gives an error that there is no animation data.
I want to do some further editing, so just exporting what I have to STL file is not going to work.

You can go to the desired frame, select all involved objects, press K and choose "Insert Visual Loc Rot Keyframe", then delete the rigid body functions.
If an object "jumps" out of place, just move the timeline cursor, in order to relaod the animation data stored.
Then you can remove all animation data from the dopesheet.

